# HTML or CSS, how is this done?

Tags: html, css

I have found a website that someone used only css and html to make a Windows 7 start menu. Also I have noticed that there is a magnifying glass in the search bar.

My question is how did this person get character/symbol there as I cant find any magnifying glasses on the web and I assume he didn't us any images for this menu.

Here is the link to the [site](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-windows-7-start-menu)

If someone is too lazy here is the pic of the site but you may not find out what it is without the source so please visit the  [site](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-windows-7-start-menu) .

[image]

Comment: [Pure css icons](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/demo/#non)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He used `::before` and `::after` on the `<form>` to draw a circle and a rotated line.

You can see it in Chrome's inspector:

```
#menu .left-menu form#search::before {
    content: "";
    width: 3px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -41px;
    top: 23px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-41deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-41deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-41deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-41deg);
    transform: rotate(-41deg);

}

#menu .left-menu form#search::after {
    content: "";
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -37px;
    top: 16px;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice those `::before` and `::after` tags